# Adding element in innerHTML appends <xml> tag?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, html-parsing

Using javascript i am adding the child  element at runtime. My code is,

```
(function () {
    var divElmt = document.createElement('div');
    var leftPane = document.getElementById('LeftHandPannelContent')
    divElmt.id = "MyPanel";
    divElmt.setAttribute('runat', 'server');
    divElmt.setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
    var htmlTag = "<x:CustomTag runat=\"server\" id=\"sample\">";
    divElmt.innerHTML = htmlTag;
    leftPane.appendChild(divElmt);
}());
```

The above method is a self-invoking function and the Tag i am using is a custom tag, the prefix of which is added at top of aspx page.

The issue is, at runtime the innerHTML has

```
"<?XML:NAMESPACE PREFIX = x/><x:CustomTag id="sample" runat="server"/>"
```

Also the attributes are suffled in undetermined order.

What may be the issue? How do i achive adding the custom tag dynamicaly in html page?

**EDIT:**

When i add the same  with custom tag at design time it is working fine. Also, if i use innerText instead of innerHTML, the text getting updated properly. But i need to render it as a html content.

Comment: Seems like you're mixing things. `<x:`, `runat` etc. are things you put in your asp.net back-end. JavaScript does not know those things and doesn't parse them as asp.net would.

Comment: Is the "x"-Namespace defined somewhere in your html-code? Also: Have you tried InnerText instead of InnerHTML?

Comment: @JoSo: ya "x" namespace is defined at top of aspx page. i tried innerText, there >xml> is not getting appended and displayed as a Text.

Comment: The html page doesn't care about the namespace definition in aspx as the javascript is executed on client side and asp doesn't expose it's inner workings to the client side. I believe what you are trying to do is add something with javascript and then let asp reinterpret the page. This is simply not going to work.

Comment: +1 @JoSo: oh yes u r rite. aspx is not going to reinterpret it. Then how do i achieve this case? any thoughts?

Comment: i'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. But i'll say: AJAX request to asp and integrate result on client side. Or, if it doesn't need to be asynchronous: Add the content in aspx, not in javascript.

Comment: One more thought: If your're using aspx you might be interested in the updatepanel. Maybe it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't

```
var htmlTag = "<x:CustomTag runat=\"server\" id="\sample\">";
```

be

```
var htmlTag = "<x:CustomTag runat=\"server\" id=\"sample\">";
```

I moved the \ before the s of sample to the left, so it's now before the " for escaping purposes.

Comment: Robin that's not an issue. Its a typo mistake here. i updated the qus now.

Comment: Fixing a string won't fix broken code though. This is like trying to call a PHP function from JS, or query an Oracle db with jQuery.